# Use if else to declare a `let` or `const` to use after the if/else?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reactjs, constants, let

I'm not sure why but it seems that I can't call the `let` or `const` variables if I declare them in an `if/else` statement.

```
if (withBorder) {
  const classes = `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
} else {
  const classes = `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
}
return (
  <div className={classes}>
    {renderedResult}
  </div>
);
```

If I use this code it says that `classes is not defined`.

But if I change the `const` to `var` classes is defined but I get a warning about `classes used outside of binding context`and `all var declarations must be at the top of the function scope`

How could I fix this?

Comment: `let` and `const` have been designed to be scoped inside control statements such as `if` and `for`. If you want to use `let` you need to define the variable before the `if` and just assign it inside.

Comment: that's expected in most programming languages. older javascript will still let you get away with it.  However, if it's a constant, the value should be assigned once and never change...  declare it as a `let` outside the if block and set it inside the if/else blocks.

Comment: Why not just use *var*?

Comment: @RobG it's not ES6y enough…

Comment: @Bergi—I'm gonna use that, especially with a Kiwi accent. :-)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a good example of where a simple ternary assignment could suffice:

```
const classes = withBorder ?
 `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center` : 
 `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`
```

As specified in other comments/answers `let` and `const` are block scoped, so that's why they don't work in your example.

For DRYer code, you can use the ternary only for the part that depends on it:

```
 const classes = (withBorder ? `${styles.circularBorder} ` : "") +
 `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`
```

Comment: ah yeah, totally forgot about inline if/else that will definitely refactor the code pretty well. thanks!

Answer (score 55):

`let` and `const` are block level scoped meaning they can only be used within the block they have been defined in ie. `{ // if defined in here can only be used here }`

In this case I would just define above the if/else statement

```
let classes;

if (withBorder) {
  classes = `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
} else {
  classes = `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
}
```

Comment: This can't be done with const, as const needs an initializer value

Comment: The example uses `let` since we are redefining a variable based on if withBorder exists only way to use `const` would to be with a ternary operator since you can't redefine a constant variable

Answer (score 39):

Alternative (not sure it's *good* nor *elegant* though):

```js
const classes = (() => {
  if (withBorder) {
    return `${styles.circularBorder}...`;
  } else {
    return `${styles.dimensions}...`;
  }
})();
```

Comment: That moment when Javascript kicks in with all it's freedom.

Comment: This sure beats nested shorthand conditionals.

Comment: Better than a switch or a nested ternary

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an `if`-`else`-statement but a ternary expression:

```
const classes = withBorder
  ? `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`
  :                          `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
```

Alternatively, just declare it outside of the `if` block, which allows you to get rid of the duplication as well:

```
let classes = `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;
if (withBorder) {
  classes += ` ${styles.circularBorder}`;
  // or if you care about the order,
  // classes = `${styles.circularBorder} ${classes}`;
}
```

Also have a look at [messy classnames construction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40753492/1048572).

Comment: Someone who understands how the judicial use of whitespace can make code easier to understand! (Boo, Prettier.)

Answer (score 4):

`let` and `const` are block level scoped, so you will have to define them outside of the block. `var` works because it hoists out.

You can defined `classes` before the `if` block like [@finalfreq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877053/use-if-else-to-declar-a-let-or-const-to-use-after-the-if-else/40877084#40877084)

or

```
let classes = `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`;

if (withBorder) {
  classes += `${styles.circularBorder}`;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ESLint standard likes the operators at the beginning of the line. Long conditionals should also be abstracted out, unless in a computer time loop.

In this particular case the strings are also long, so I would abstract those out too. Problem with Bergi's way is most linters will cripple his style, for conformance reasons.

This way keeps everything normal and easy to read, if you are familiar with ternaries, which you should be.

```
const styleWithBorder = `${styles.circularBorder} ${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`
const styleWithoutBorder = `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`
const classes = isBorderedElement ? [ styleWithBorder ] : [ styleWithoutBorder ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple**, just do this:

```
const genericStyle = `${styles.dimensions} ${styles.circularPadding} row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center`,

classes = withBorder ? `${styles.circularBorder} ${genericStyle}` : genericStyle;

return (
  <div className={classes}>
    {renderedResult}
  </div>
);
```

This has some clean-up also, the class used twice and only `circularBorder` is the difference...