# How to use if statement to declare a new variable with ES6? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, constants, let

How can I optionally declare a variable using `let` or `const`?
For example it would be possible to do:

```
if (variableNotMade) {
  var makeVariable
}
```

But how can this be achieved using `let` or `const` instead of `var`? 
A similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877053/use-if-else-to-declare-a-let-or-const-to-use-after-the-if-else) shows that it's possible to do:

```
let makeVariable = variableNotMade ? foo : bar
```

Although this approach only really works if you have an `else`.
Is there a suitable way to achieve this or should a different approach be taken?

Comment: It does not make sense to declare a variable with `var` inside an `if` statement because the variable will be hoisted to the function scope anyway. You can do it with `let` or `const` but the variable is only defined within the enclosing block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not "conditionally create variables". You can conditionally assign values to a variable, but not conditionally create it.

Take this example and assume it would work as you expect:

```
if (foo) {
    var bar = 'baz';
}

alert(bar);
```

So what if `foo` is `false`, then `bar` isn't being created, then `alert(bar)` would raise an error about an undefined variable?! No, this is insane.

That's why `var` declarations will be hoisted and the variable *will* exist, merely with an `undefined` value. And it's why `let` and `const` are explicitly block scoped; they *will* exist inside their block, and they *won't* exist outside their block. So you can never get into a situation in which a "conditionally created variable" doesn't exist.

What you want is probably:

```
let foo;

if (bar) {
    foo = 'baz';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is not such thing as an *optional declaration*. You declare the variable and then the assignment can be optional if you can call it that (better say conditional). Finally check for null.

Also `let` `const` and `var` are different things:
`let` has a block scope, `const` is read only and block scoped and finally `var` has a function scope. There is a lot more involved in using them safely cause hey, it's JS, but that's is the summary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the else block you can do this

> let makeVariable = variableNotMade && foo

but this will set makeVariable to false. 
So, if this is not what you specifically want, you should use deceze♦ method.